# How to create a global counter in angular as a service

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I wanted to know, how can I change a global value via a "service"?

I build an simple app-services, which includes a "count"-variable and a "increase"-function.

```
myApp.service("itemCount", function(){
  var count = 1;
  this.count = count;
  return {
    count: this.count,
    increase: function(){
      this.count = this.count + 1;
      return this.count;
    }
  // maxItems: --> TodoCtrl $scopes.todos.length 
  }
});
```

I build up a simple todo-list:

```
myApp.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http, itemCount) {
  $http.get('todos.json')
       .success(function(data){
          $scope.todos = data;       
          var start = 0;
          $scope.todo = $scope.todos[start];
          $scope.nextTodo = function(num){
            if(num < $scope.todos.length){
              $scope.todo = $scope.todos[num];
              itemCount.increase();
              console.log("count = " + itemCount.count);
            }
          };
        });
});
```

At least I build a "progress"-control:

```
myApp.controller('ProgressCtrl', function ($scope, itemCount) {

    $scope.max = 10; // hard coded
    $scope.value = itemCount.count;

});
```

How can I achieve, that my "progress"-control gets the latest count value?

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/dCinO4iGDfql40GStGr2

Thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the value using a function rather than the variable or add the service to the scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/LBISC3RhIAKgtgXJjUDD?p=preview

```
{{getCount()}} / {{max}}
{{itemService.count}} / {{max}}


myApp.controller('ProgressCtrl', function ($scope, itemCount) {
    $scope.max = 10; // hard coded
    $scope.value = itemCount.count;
    $scope.getCount = function(){ return itemCount.count; };
    $scope.itemService = itemCount;
});
```